# ASP.NET Jquery UI Button not rendering properly

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been having a lot of trouble having the theme I load render properly in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application... I've been doing a lot of research, but I think it might be related to the dialog issues I've been having as well... Can anyone please help me out?

From what I understand, I need to reference what class of button I want to use like this:

```
    <button class="ui-button" id="overview">Overview</button>
```

But it still renders the button as just a gray button, no theme.

Here are my bundles:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/ui-darkness/css").Include(
            "~/Content/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css"));
```

And here is my Layout:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/ui-darkness/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Also of note is that Intellisense does not have any tooltips for .button() or .dialog().

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I've attached a picture of the non-stylized button "overview" 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kohZH.png

Comment: Please add a screen-shot to explain "not rendering properly"

Answer (score 0):

I think when you downlod the JS and CSS file related to jqueryui with out check dialog and button option

go to http://jqueryui.com/download/ and check all the check box and download the js and csss file and use in your project.[image]

Comment: Hi P John, I've done this already, but it is not correctly changing the button image or theme.

Answer (score 0):

You should not had Theme/base CSS.

I do'nt use the same Theme, but It work's here with :

BUNDLE

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                 "~/Content/Css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css",
                  "~/Content/Css/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/Css/font-awesome.min.css",
                  "~/Content/Css/site.css"));
```

LAYOUT

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

VIEW

```
    <button class="ui-button" id="overview">Overview</button>
```

jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css came from \jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom\css\smoothness\

It's enough to add the CSS you find in your theme folder.

Comment: Hi JDahm, I tried adding it to that bundle as well. The only thing that changed is the shape of the button is slightly different, but none of the changes that should be in the theme. It continues to be a normal gray button... Could something be preventing this css from working? I'm very unfamiliar with all of this.

Comment: I think something might be wrong with all my java references because I'm currently having issues with themes, creating a proper dialog box, and ajax paging. I feel like I'm fighting 5 different fires.

Comment: There is a conflict between Bootstrap and jquery UI if you use both. A good Idea to track where your error is, is to start from a new project and just adding jquery ui to try to add a button

Comment: Hmmmm... would that cause issues with everything I'm talking about? I get the feeling it might. What exactly does Bootstrap do? I think I might pull all the css and scripts from a project where I know at least paging works and see what happens... Thanks for your help, I'll let you know what happens!

Comment: Hi JDahm, I'm still really confused. Sometimes I'll think it's going to work according to what I've been reading on how to avoid the conflicts between bootstrap and jquery and even paging as well, but it just refuses to work correctly... Do I need to manually go through bootstrap and delete everything that might be in conflict? I'm at a loss as to where to go next.